# Eloquent json field- get records higher/lower than some value

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have column `data` with json type in my table. That query doesn't work:

```
Advert::where('data->price', '>', 2000)->get();
```

In response I got elements with price lower than 2000. QueryBuilder run this on db:

```
SELECT * FROM "adverts" WHERE "data"->>'price' > '2000'
```

I have no idea what is wrong. It looks like price is casting to string but in database is saved as integer.

```
{"price": 500}
```

Comment: Can you paste your "config > database.php" settings?

Comment: I have standard config. After the change proposed by Jonas everything works as I expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL compares the values as strings, beginning with the first character. That's why 500 is "higher" than 2000. You need to convert the price to an integer using a raw expression:

```php
Advert::where(DB::raw('("data"->>\'price\')::int'), '>', 2000)->get();
```